# Ionic 4 - add external vanilla JS library into my project

Tags: angular, ionic4, mercadopago

I am trying to import this JS library into my Ionic 4 project: 'https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js' to use it in my angular componets. I've been looking all over the web without solution.

I tried to import into my angular.json file but is not working.

```
"scripts": ["https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"]
```

Also I tried to import directly from my index.html but it seems is not able to read it.

Docs [link](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/api/receiving-payment-by-card/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

### home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var Mercadopago: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor() {
    console.log(Mercadopago);
  }
}
```

### index.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
<script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, can you please explain a bit further how and why?

Comment: When application get build and all resources goes in bundle file and so we have to declare variable like declare var Mercadopago. Another example if you want to user jquery then you add js file in index.html and declare $ in page where you want to use